# Copy and Paste Macro to specific Column Ranges

Tags: excel, vba, insert, copy

I've created a macro in Excel to copy a row in one of my sheets and insert the row into another sheet above the user's selected row. The macro is as follows and works correctly:

```
Sub addTestProductRow()
    Sheets("Macro templates").Range("B2:J2").Copy
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
End Sub
```

However, I wish to add to this macro to make it only insert in the columns B to J, regardless of which cell the user has selected. I still wish for it to insert above the users selected row, just in the specified column range.

Comment: How is the user calling the function? Do they select the cells and then click a button? You can extract just the row of the selected worksheet and use the information to generate your copy range. Is this what you are thinking?

Comment: The user selects a cell and presses the hotkey (ctrl-i) and this will call the function and insert the row (with column ranges B - J) and paste it above the cell the user has selected.

The problem is, that if the user doesn't have a cell in column B selected the row is inserted and the formatting is ruined as the row doesn't line up with columns B to J

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
Sub addTestProductRow()
    Dim t As Long
    t = Selection.Row
    Rows(t).Insert
    Sheets("Macro templates").Range("B2:J2").Copy
    Range("B" & t).PasteSpecial

End Sub
```

Comment: This is perfect and does exactly what I want, however the row contains a checkbox. This isn't pasted when the macro is called. Im guessing this is because of the PasteSpecial, is there a way to make it paste the checkbox aswell?